# Prevents Npm lifecycle "prepare" script from installing devDependencies when installing from private github repository

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'd like `npm install` to only add the compiled files of a project hosted in a private repository on Github. So here is the relevant part of what I did in my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "npm run build",
  "build": "rollup -c",
  "dev": "rollup -c -w",
  "start": "sirv public --dev",
  "prettify": "prettier --write --list-different .",
  "lint": "eslint --fix ."
},
...
"files": [
  "public/build/",
  "**/*.md"
]
```

Then I just `npm install --omit=dev github:name/personnal-project#feat/test`. Everything got installed as expected BUT it turns out `devDependencies` are also installed. The thing is they are totally useless to the user adding the project to production (it's just tools for code quality, like eslint).

From the NPM [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install), I can see that:

> As with regular git dependencies, dependencies and devDependencies will be installed if the package has a prepare script before the package is done installing.

How can I prevent this behaviour and just install `Dependencies` ? Publishing a private package on npm or github's registries is not an option for me. And I did not had any success installing binaries from a Github release hosted in a private repo.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried including the [`--production`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) flag? Its description states; _"npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`"_.

Comment: @RobC after further exploration, it seems that Yarn is the culprit (my project should be installed via yarn as well as npm). Seems like yarn add ignore the `--production` flag (tried different way with no success). Any idea on that?